# How to copy few variables to other variable?

Tags: c++

For example,

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo(uint8_t b0, uint8_t b1, uint16_t b23)
    {
        // some code here
    }
    uint32_t m_n;
};
```

I can write something like this:

```
auto dest = reinterpret_cast<uint8_t*>(&m_n);
memcpy(dest, &b0, sizeof(b0));
memcpy(dest + sizeof(b0), &b1, sizeof(b1));
memcpy(dest + sizeof(b0) + sizeof(b1), &b23, sizeof(b23));
```

But it's very ugly. And what to do when there are 15 such variables (do not ask why)

Comment: Sorry, but I have to ask, why?  Knowing your use case can help us come up with a proper solution.

Comment: you have a solution + you forbid us to ask what is the use case... how are we supposed to provide alternatives when you dont want to disclose what this is for?!?

Comment: You're making a int32 out of an int8, an int8  and an int16. You will want to look into bitwise arithmetic.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `reinterpret_cast` is almost for sure undefined behavior.

Comment: Consider bit shifting applicability?

Comment: There is an ancient interface with a constructor in the form of 16 variables of 1 byte each. I need to initialize some 16 byte structure with them

Comment: @ИгорьПугачев Whether that's legal depends on the 16 byte structure. Is it [standard layout](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/StandardLayoutType)? Then constructing it from `memcp`'d values can be fine. Otherwise it's probably not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible implementation (needs C++17, or see below):

```
template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr void combine_as_bits_impl(std::size_t offset, unsigned char* out, 
                                    const T& x, const Ts&... xs) {
    std::memcpy(out + offset, &x, sizeof(T));
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) > 0)
        combine_as_bits_impl(offset + sizeof(T), out, xs...);
}

template<typename Out, typename... Ts>
constexpr Out combine_as_bits(const Ts&... xs) {
    static_assert((sizeof(Ts) + ...) == sizeof(Out));

    unsigned char buff[sizeof(Out)];
    combine_as_bits_impl(0, buff, xs...);

    Out out;
    std::memcpy(&out, buff, sizeof(Out));
    return out;
}
```

Usage examples:

```
auto s = combine_as_bits<std::uint32_t>(
             std::uint8_t{0x1}, std::uint8_t{0x2}, std::uint16_t{0x3456});
assert(s == 0x34560201);
```

and

```
Foo(std::uint8_t b0, std::uint8_t b1, std::uint16_t b23) : 
    m_n(combine_as_bits<std::uint32_t>(b0, b1, b23)) {}
```

If `if constexpr` is not available, simple overloading can be used to terminate recursion:

```
constexpr void combine_as_bits_impl(std::size_t, unsigned char*) {}

template<typename T, typename... Ts>
constexpr void combine_as_bits_impl(std::size_t offset, unsigned char* out, 
                                    const T& x, const Ts&... xs) {
    std::memcpy(out + offset, &x, sizeof(T));
    combine_as_bits_impl(offset + sizeof(T), out, xs...);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm suspecting you need this kind of function:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_integral_v<T>, std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(T)>>
littleEndianBytes(T value)
{
    static_assert(sizeof(uint8_t) == 1);
    using result_type = std::array<uint8_t, sizeof(T)>;
    result_type result;
    for(auto& x : result) {
        x = value & 0xFF;
        value >>= 8;
    }

    return result;
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/ooGuIzZaw8tdffaT

Comment: Isn't that the wrong direction?

Comment: got confused by quality of question. I will provide other direction too.

Comment: What's the purpose of `static_assert`?

Answer (score 3):

In the particular case you've shown, you could move the given arguments into the target using bit-shifting (as suggested in the comments) and logical ORing, which would give code like this:

```cpp
m_n = (b23 << 16) | (b1 << 8) | b0;
```

But this is very specific to the case you have given. If your other variables have different types and/or you want to copy things differently, you would have to adapt the code to suit each purpose.

Another way (using the same example), but which is more easily adaptable to different target types, would be something like this:

```cpp
uint8_t bytes[4] = { b0, b1, uint8_t(b23 & 0xFF), uint8_t(b23 >> 8) };
memcpy(&m_n, bytes, 4);
```

where you first initialize a byte array to the arguments given (could easily be increased to 16 bytes) and then use `memcpy` to move the byte array into the target.

This latter approach could be further 'optimized' by making `bytes` a member of `Foo` and setting up its values in an initializer list:

```cpp
struct Foo
{
    Foo(uint8_t b0, uint8_t b1, uint16_t b23) : bytes{ b0, b1, uint8_t(b23 & 0xFF), uint8_t(b23 >> 8) }
    {
        memcpy(&m_n, bytes, 4);
    }
    uint8_t bytes[4];
    uint32_t m_n;
};
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

Comment: Pessimized rather. You double the size of `Foo` for no reason.

Comment: @Evg Hehe - optimized or not is here subjective: size versus simplicity. But, one could change the `struct` to a `union` (boo, hiss) - then no size increase, and no need for the `memcpy`. (But definitely ***not*** recommending this!!)

Comment: @Evg - Fixed! Thanks for pointing it out.